# Application upgrade version delete settings file

Tags: xamarin.forms

Dears ,
I Build Xamarin-forms Application and
I am trying to Save Settings for my application in JSON format in file in Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments

But when I Upgrade The Version for the App on Android , The file deleted . I tried also to save it in Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData But the file deleted also , do you suggest any location to save the file so when install new Version of the App the Data not deleted , or advise me a way to save settings file and not delete it when upgrade . Thanks .

Comment: You could have a try with [External storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=macos) to store file.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT incaste there is no external storage in the device that will be faild

Comment: Hi, the external storage is the area outside of app sandbox, every phone has it. You could have a look at this document again.